# Salesforce as identity provider do not provide SSO for partner and customer users in community

Tags: community, single-sign-on, identity

I have setup a community with some customer and partner users using a developer account.

I have also enabled Salesforce as an identity provider (IdP). In the community login page, I added a login option using the organization IdP through SAML SSO.

Internal users can successfully use the login option provided in the community login page. However, customer and partner users in the community does not succeeed. Identity Provider Event Log and Login History does not show any login trace of customer and partner users.

Does Salesforce provide IdP for customers and partners in Community Cloud? I can't find much documentation and guidelines talking about Salesforce as an identity provider.

Is it common to use Salesforce as an identity provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find the answers to your question in these two posts here on SF.SE: [Basic SSO concepts and how Salesforce fits in](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41727/basic-sso-concepts-and-how-salesforce-fits-in) and [SSO with OAuth for Communities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43803/sso-with-oauth-for-communities). The first post asks questions very close to yours and receives some fairly specific answers that I think you'll find helpful while the second is more general. The resources provided as links are what you'll need to look at to resolve any issues you're having.